# TCP server socket is closed if i switched to another app

Tags: java, android

Finally i succeeded opening tcp (client-server) socket,

but the problem is when i switch between my server app & other apps, then switch back to my Server app i found that server socket is closed ...!

I made the server socket open in a thread.

i think that my problem is in "stopping thread when switching to another app, and then Restarting thread when switching back to my app"

Note:
I didn't implement "onPuse or onStop".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In android, the decision whether to keep your app running or not depends a lot on the existence of a `Context` whether it is an `Activity`, `Service` or `BroadcastReceiver`.

According to android's documentation:

> An empty process is one hosting no activities or other application components (such as Service or BroadcastReceiver classes). These are killed very quickly by the system as memory becomes low. For this reason, any background operation you do outside of an activity must be executed in the context of an activity BroadcastReceiver or Service to ensure that the system knows it needs to keep your process around.

So what do you want to do is starting a service once your activity is started and from that service spawn a thread that will manage the TCP server. that way you will be fine as long as the process is running.

here is a link describing the state of a process in android: [ProcessLifecycle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ProcessLifecycle)

And for more about services, checkout this [Link](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidServices/article.html)

Comment: thanks alot Mr.Me, but can i open TCP server socket in a service without threads ?

Comment: yes you can, but you shouldn't because service runs on the main thread (UI Thread) so you will block the UI

Comment: Then should i open TCP server socket from thread inside a service ?

Comment: Will the socket close if i switched to another app & switch back to my app ?

Comment: Yes you should open the server from a thread inside the service, and no it should keep running regardless of the user navigation.

Comment: Can services change my activity UI "EX: Text views"